# .append not working in Notepad++

Tags: jquery, html, notepad++

I'm trying to make my own to-do list application, but the first step isn't even working!
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-Do List</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

    <!--JAVASCRIPT-->
    <script>
     </script>

        <script src="jquery.js"></script>

        <!--JQUERY--> 
<script>

$(function() {
  $("#new").click(function() {
     $("html").append("<div><form> Category Name: <input type = \"text\">")
    });
});

</script>
</head>

   <!--USER INTERFACE-->
   <div>
   <p id = "new">New Category</p>
   </div>

   <div><p>Customize</p></div>

   <div><p>Save this list</p></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the application up in Notepad++(Latest version of Chrome), nothing happens when I click on 'New Category'. Any help?

Comment: `$("html").append`???

Comment: Notepad++, latest version of Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending a `div` to the `html` element:

```
$("html").append("<div><form> Category Name: <input type = \"text\">")
```

You should put it in the `body` or below, not in the `html` element.

```
$("body").append("<div><form> Category Name: <input type = \"text\">")
```

While some browsers ***may*** show the `div` anyway, you're creating an invalid structure. Sticking to a valid one is probably best.

(Note that creating this via the DOM is totally different from actually writing an HTML file with that content. There are ["optional" tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) in *serialized* HTML — such as that from a file or URL — but that's different from building an invalid structure via the DOM.)

It's also probably a good idea to include the closing tags in the fragment you're appending:

```
$("body").append("<div><form> Category Name: <input type = \"text\"></form></div>")
// Here ------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...although in my experiment jQuery didn't care.

Comment: Also don't forget to close the tags on `append()`, like `form` and `div`

Answer (score 0):

You must put a `<body>` tag after your `</head>`.
And it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jquery locally in your project folder? Your relative script path indicates so. I created what you have in jsfiddle (including jquery), and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/3qjFg/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <a href="#" id="new">New Category</a>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Customize</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Save this list</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#new").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("body").append("<div><form> Category Name: <input type = \"text\">");
  });
});
```